# Codeigniter tank auth

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

I am wondering if someone can help me, I have recently moved my site live to test it so I basically copied the database and uploaded the files. This means that I had already set up a user account on my local server. However, I have found the login to be a bit temperamental, when I went to login it wouldn’t accept it so I had to reset my password which it then worked fine. Then I decided to register another user and that worked fine however I went to log in the next day and it wouldn’t let me, even though I know that the details were correct…

Has anyone else experienced something similar? Also, if you have, how did you fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember with Tank Auth is that the password hashes are localized to a single server, and will not work on any other.  You can change that inside the tank_auth config file by changing `phpass_hash_portable` to true, but this is less safe.  My recommendation is to just recreate the accounts.

That is the only problem I can think of in your situation, hope if fixes it.